# Preprocessor Loop '#rep #endrep' don't work on Xcode?

Tags: ios, assembly, preprocessor, arm

I want to repeat part of arm assembly code, like nasm preprocessor does:

```
 #rep 4
 .......
 vadd.u8 q0,q2
 .......
 #endrep
```

It pass compile but not really work. Any idea?Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.rept`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/as/Rept.html#Rept)

```
.rept 4
  ……
  vadd.u8 q0, q2
  ……
.endr
```

---

Edit: OK, turns out the iPhone SDK is using an ancient version of GNU as (1.38), so `.rept` cannot be used. You could use a macro to simulate this though, e.g.

```
.macro dummy_macro_ahjd
 .if $0
  vadd.u8 q0, q2
  dummy_macro_ahjd ($0-1)
 .endif
.endmacro

main:
 dummy_macro_ahjd 4
```

Comment: fail to compile, Xcode4.2 show "Unknown pseudo-op: .rept/.endr"